# What is the average number of dice rolls to obtain 2 specific numbers?

Tags: probability, dice

Say I have a 10 sided dice, and I want to know the average number of rolls it would take me to roll both a 9 and a 10, disregarding repeat numbers, what would the maths look like for this?
For context, imagine in a game an opponent has a 1/100 chance of dropping 4 specific rare items. How many kills on average would it take to obtain all 4?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you, say, determine the expected number of rolls it takes to get a $9$?

Comment: "disregarding repeat numbers" can you elaborate on this part a bit further? Does this mean we can assume that our dice is *magical* so that we can't ever roll something we previously rolled?

Comment: @Iulu I know the expected number of rolls to get a specific number on an n-sided dice is simply n.

Comment: @WaveX I more meant that I wasn't asking for the chance of getting a 9 and a 10 without repeats, I put that poorly, I just meant that any 10 rolled after the first 10 should be treated like any other number.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a sequence of Bernoulli trials with probability of success $p$, then the average number of trials until the first success is $\frac1p.$  The trick here is to consider two events.  The first is that either a $9$ or a $10$ shows up.  the probability of success is $\frac15$ so the expected number of trials is $5$.  After that you have to wait for the number that didn't show up to occur.  That takes $10$ rolls on average, so in all the expected waiting time is $15$ rolls.

Comment: And the other one (for finding all four rare items) would be $$\dfrac{100}{4}+\dfrac{100}{3}+\dfrac{100}{2}+\dfrac{100}{1}$$ correct?

Comment: @saulspatz That makes a lot of sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution makes use of the Coupon Collector's Problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

In terms of the dice, we'll call a successful roll one where you roll either of the 9 or 10.  The coupon collector's problem will tell you the expected number of successful rolls needed until both the 9 and the 10 are rolled: when n=2, expect to require 3 successful rolls.  Now we can say a successful roll happens 20% of the time (the chances of rolling a 9 or 10 on a 10-sided die = 2/10).  This means you should expect 1 successful roll for every 5 rolls.  To get 3 successful rolls you should expect 5*3 = 15 total rolls.

In terms of the game opponent, let's say a "successful drop" is when one of the four items is dropped (regardless of whether it was dropped previously).  The coupon collector's problem tells us to expect to need 9 successful drops to get all 4 items.  We know the odds of getting a successful drop are 4/100 = 1/25 = 1 successful drop in 25 drops.  This means we should expect 9*25 = 225 total drops before all 4 rare items are received.  I was looking into this for Runescape drops so thought I'd come back to answer the question for you after I understood it.

I apologize for not deriving the Coupon Collector's Problem here and for not formatting the math elements.  This is my first post here.

Comment: With four coupons, the expected number of coupons that must be collected is $25/3=8.333\ldots$, not $9$. You can confirm this by the formula. The chart on Wikipedia is not accurate.